# sprite kit Restitution change during animation

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I want to do simple pinball game, and want to change restitution during action of moving left or right side of pinball arms

This is the code of left action

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if location.x < 375 && location.y < 750 {
            flip_left?.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI/3.0), duration: 0.08  ),

                ]))

        }
        else  { flip_left?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5 }
```

Comment: What is your question ? It's good to put some code sample, but could you please explain your problem a bit more ? And what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I don't see a problem either

Comment: The ball (with a physics body) will not interact correctly with the flipper unless you move the flipper's physics body with `angularVelocity` or `applyAngularImpulse`.

Comment: Hello, there, it was my first post here. This code is simple moving left arm of pinball, after move , after touch release the restitution going back to the 0.5, but I want it to go to the restitution = 1 during movement of arm, to simulate that arm giving bigger force to the ball during move. Without that arm just softly kicks the ball, and it is not real like in pinball.

Comment: @Rafalisko What are you saying? In your code there isn't arm (flip_left) moving  action, I see a rotation ad a change of restitution. I think you must review your question content, seems you forgot to report some code..

Comment: There is rotation ofcourse, but this is moviement anyway.... I want to give kick to the ball when arm is rotating, whe only way I know is to change restitution of arm to bigger value. But when I did this its like ball is kicked every time contacts arm, even if arm is in upper position and not rotating what is not looking good. So in code I pasted is only roll back to value of restitution of 0.5, I want to change restituion while arm is rotating to 1. Or is any other way to give force of kick for ball, when arm is rotating. Standard physics is not enaough to it looks real.